# how to show complete data in listbox using c# for windows phone

Tags: c#, listbox

I am developing an app where i need to show data from web service in a listbox. I am able to show data in my listbox but its not showing the complete data. There is some problem on managing the width of my box which i am not able to fix. Can anyone please help. Here is the code:

```
 <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
       <ScrollViewer Margin="0,17,0,49" VerticalScrollBarVisibility ="Visible"  AllowDrop="False" ManipulationMode="Control">
            <ListBox Name="listBox1" Margin="68,106,58,662">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Width="300"  Height="120">
                            <Button.Content>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="80" Width="80" Margin="0,0,0,0">
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Height="80">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=News_Title}" TextWrapping="Wrap" ></TextBlock>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=News_Description}" TextWrapping="Wrap"></TextBlock>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Date_Start}" TextWrapping="Wrap"></TextBlock>

                                    </StackPanel>
                            </StackPanel>
                            </Button.Content>
                        </Button>
                </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: also add more tags related to windows phone development, This would let Wp developers know about your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is fine here, just few things were making the code messy, I have fixed them.

See the updated grid now :)

```
 <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">


            <ListBox Name="listBox1">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button>
                            <Button.Content>
                            <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Height="80" Width="400">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,0">
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Height="80">
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=News_Title}" TextWrapping="Wrap" ></TextBlock>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=News_Description}" TextWrapping="Wrap"></TextBlock>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Date_Start}" TextWrapping="Wrap"></TextBlock>

                                    </StackPanel>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Button.Content>
                        </Button>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>

    </Grid>
```

Check this, it would help :)

Comment: The problem is that the complete data is not showing. Suppose the data that has to be shown is Stackoverflow. Then it shows only a part of it like Stacko.

Comment: Its working but still for big sentences the complete data is not coming. Is there any tag to auto adjust the box

Comment: okays, you need to turn scrollviewers HorizontalScrollbarVisibility to "Auto". Check the edits and see now, also why are you putting them inside a button? Is it a need ?

Comment: No its not a need. I just need to show the data from webservice and when new data is entered it should be updated.

Comment: okay, then you need to call the service again when the data updates, and reassign the itemsource to listbox. This would refresh the data and the listbox.